# Python-Twisted Reactor Starting too Early

Tags: python, twisted

I have an application that uses PyQt4 and python-twisted to maintain a connection to another program.  I am using "qt4reactor.py" as found [here](https://code.launchpad.net/qt4reactor).  This is all packaged up using py2exe.  The application works wonderfully for 99% of users, but one user has reported that networking is *failing* completely on his Windows system.  No other users report the issue, and I cannot replicate it on my own Windows VM.  The user *reports* no abnormal configuration.

The debugging logs show that the `reactor.connectTCP()` call is executing *immediately*, even though the reactor hasn't been started yet! There's no mistaking run order because this is a single-threaded process with 60 sec of computation and multiple log messages between this line and when the reactor is supposed to start.

There's a lot of code, so I am only putting in pseudo-code, hoping that there is a general solution for this issue.  I will link to the actual code below it.

```
import qt4reactor
qt4reactor.install()

# Start setting up main window
# ...

from twisted.internet import reactor

# Separate listener for detecting/processing multiple instances
self.InstanceListener = ListenerFactory(...)
reactor.listenTCP(LISTEN_PORT, self.InstanceListener)

# The active/main connection
self.NetworkingFactory = ClientFactory(...)
reactor.connectTCP(ACTIVE_IP, ACTIVE_PORT, self.NetworkingFactory)

# Finish setting up main window
# ...

from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.runReturn()
```

The code is nested throughout the [Armory project files](https://github.com/etotheipi/BitcoinArmory). ArmoryQt.py (containing the above code) and armoryengine.py (containing the `ReconnectingClientFactory` subclass used for this connection).

So, the `reactor.connectTCP()` call executes immediately.  The client code executes the send command and then immediately `connectionLost()` gets called.  It does not appear to try to reconnect.  It also doesn't throw any errors other than `connectionLost()`.  Even more mysteriously, it receives messages from the remote node later on, and this app even processes them! But it believes it's not connected (and handshake never finished, so the remote node *shouldn't* be sending messages, but might be a bug/oversight in that program).

What on earth is going on!?  How could the reactor get started before I tell it to start?  I searched the code and found no other code that (I believe) could start the reactor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you can put in enough code to reproduce the problem (and strip out everything extraneous), that will make it way more likely that people can help you.  In particular, you should try making a [Short, Self-Contained, (Compilable) Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  I'm usually good about doing that... except this issue isn't reproducible on any system I've ever used, so I don't think the full code sample would be worth filling the page!  (not to mention twisted client factory classes take up a lot of space)

Comment: that's reasonable, and it looks like someone else understands it, which is really all that matters. Also nice username :)

Answer (score 0):

The API that you're looking for is [twisted.internet.reactor.callWhenRunning](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorCore.html#callWhenRunning).

However, it wouldn't hurt to have less than 60 seconds of computation at startup, either :).  Perhaps you should spread that out, or delegate it to a thread, if it's relatively independent?

Comment: I thought that all calls were queued up to be called-when-running anyway...?  So should I replace the connectTCP(IP,PORT,FACTORY) with reactor.callWhenRunning(reactor.connectTCP, IP, PORT, FACTORY)?

The 60 sec load time is unfortunate, but it comes with benefits the users like.  It's due to having to read and process 2.5 GB of data from disk.  I'm actually working on trying to thread it into the background, now.  But I don't think that will make a ton of difference to this question.

Comment: Nope.  Many of these calls are invoked immediately, so that (for example) listening sockets can be known to be listening.

Comment: So then, why does this work the way I expected on the other 99% of systems I run it on?  It "calls" connectTCP(), does some other processing, but then actually executes the connection when the reactor is started.  This seems inconsistent.

Comment: I have no idea what's unusual about this one computer.  Listen queue depth, perhaps?  Is your service under load?